# Laravel Auth Check For An Organization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

when a user tries to register I require them to enter an organization ID, I want that organization ID to be checked against my Organization table and see if it exists. If it exists then register the user and if it fails then return an error message. I've been looking around online and couldn't personally find anything like this. If anybody could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I am using **Laravel 5.6** with the default auth.

Validator:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'org_id' => 'required|string|max:16',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

User Create:

```
 return User::create([
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                'org_id' => $data['org_id'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'is_active' => 1
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `exists` rule of Laravel's Validation:

```
'org_id' => 'required|string|max:16|exists:organizations,id',
```

The rule is essentially

```
exists:{table},{column?}
```

Where `table` is required, and `column` is optional, generally used if the `name` (in this case `org_id`) is different from the column you want to compare.

For full details, check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-exists).

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Anytime :) Glad to help!